# React Native 0.64.2, React-Redux 7.2.4, cannot get props to work "undefined is not an object"

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to get React-Redux to work in my new React-Native app and am not succeeding. In my attempts to find online help, all of the examples are using Classes for each Component/Screen, but the beginning React Native template app is no longer using Classes. Everything is defined using "const" and the main App function is defined as:

```
`const App: () => Node = () => {...`
```

which are all new to me and I'm not sure if it has anything to do with my failures.

I have several Components/Screens all working nicely and do not have errors until I try to implement Redux.

**Reducer:**

```
const initState = {
  syncedDate: '01/02/2022'
}
const projectsReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'PJS_SET_SYNCEDDATE':
      return {
        ...state,
        syncedDate: action.syncedDate
      }
      break;
    default:
  }
  return state
}
export default projectsReducer;
```

**Action:**

```
export const pjsSetSyncedDate = (syncedDate) => {
  return {
    type: 'PJS_SET_SYNCEDDATE',
    syncedDate
  }
}
```

**Store:**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import projectsReducer from '../reducers/projects';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  projects: projectsReducer
});
const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(rootReducer);
};
export default configureStore;
```

**App:**

```
...

const store = configureStore();

...

const App: () => Node = () => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator

...

        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
};

...
```

**Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import type { Node } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export const DetailsScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const { name } = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details List</Text>
      <Text>Incoming param: {JSON.stringify(name)}</Text>
      <Text>SyncedDate: {this.props.syncedDate}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    syncedDate: state.projects.syncedDate
  }
};

export default ConnectedDetailsScreen = connect(mapStateToProps)(DetailsScreen);
```

The error occurs in the Text block

```
"this.props.syncedDate" - undefined is not an object
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing some old implementation with the new one. try to change their step by step:

As a best practice, use `payload` property to pass your data through your action, so add it in your action.js:

```
export const pjsSetSyncedDate = (syncedDate) => {
  return {
    type: 'PJS_SET_SYNCEDDATE',
    payload: syncedDate // -----> added here
  }
}
```

So, change your reducer to get new `syncedData` with payload:

```
const initState = {
  syncedDate: '01/02/2022'
}

const projectsReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'PJS_SET_SYNCEDDATE':
      return {
        ...state,
        syncedDate: action.payload.syncedDate   // -------> add payload here
      }
      // break; 
    default:
  }
  return state
}

export default projectsReducer;
```

**Note:** you don't need the `break` expression in the `switch/case` since you returning the result in the `case`. I commented out this line in the above reducer code.

Now, back to the component `DetailsScreen`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text,View } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'; // -----> import useSelector instead of connect method

export const DetailsScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const { name } = route.params;
  
  const syncedData = useSelector(state => state.projects.syncedData)

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details List</Text>
      <Text>Incoming param: {JSON.stringify(name)}</Text>
      <Text>SyncedDate: {syncedDate}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};


export default DetailsScreen;
```

**Note:** `useSelector` hook will get the state with a selector function. you define your reducer as `projects` in the `combineReducers` so your `syncedData`  is in your `state.projects`

**Note:** with the above procedure, you don't need to connect your `DetailsScreen` to the store to get the state. `useSelector` hook will do that.